# RethinkDB update and replace-without in one line

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

Can anyone think if an elegant way to do `update` and `replace` in one line?

I want to use the `r.row.without` to remove fields and update at the same query.

Something like:

```
r.db('db').table('table').get('item_id')
          .update({ field_a:'value_a'})
          .replace(r.row.without(r.args(['field_b'])))`
```

simply chaining would be nice but this **won't work** (update returns a change result).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
r.db('db').table('table').get('item_id')
    .replace(
        r.row.merge(
            function(doc){ 
                return {field_a: 'newval'}
            }
        ).without('field_b')
    )
```

Should do the trick

Comment: Thanks @Neil, works like a chame!
I think you can do it without the anonymous function as well.

`r.row.merge({field_a: 'newval'}).without('field_b')`

Answer (score 3):

You can also write `.update({field_a: 'value_a', field_b: r.literal()})` to change one field and remove another field at the same time.

Comment: thanks @mlucy,  thats great to know, although I think the previous is more declarative !

Comment: This answer is easier/readable/straight-forward than the currently selected correct answer